# Facebook API cover images offsets in background-position attributes

Tags: facebook, css, facebook-graph-api, background-image, background-position

**!!! If anyone can answer this now, I will wait for the bounty period to end, and up it to 150 before awarding it. (Scouts honour!) !!!**

I have looked around but can't find an answer to this question:

I am getting event cover images from fb api, and also storing the offset_x and offset_y values. Then I place the images as css background-images like this:

**CSS**

```
  .event-image {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 178px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: none;
  }
```

The height/width is based on the exact ratio used by facebook: 2,8:1

**HTML**

```
<div class="event-image" style="background-image: url([url of img]);  background-position: [offset_x]% [offset_y]%;" >
```

(I do have some internal logic that only adds the background-position property if there is one set in the fb api.)

The problem is that this only works 90% of the time. Roughly 10 % of the images are slightly miss-aligned. usually only by a few percentage points :-(

Here is an example.

```css
.event-image {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 178px;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="event-image" style="background-image: url(https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-0/p180x540/14566476_1295215523823549_1334771895810946224_o.jpg);  background-position: 0% 50%; "> </div>
<!-- Offsets are taken directly from API -->
```

Now here is the [actual event](https://www.facebook.com/events/639058886272945)

You can see that actually the offset would be perfect at 46% - so why is fb giving 50%?

The most info I can find is on [pixel calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393742/how-to-compute-facebook-graph-api-cover-offset-y-to-pixel), but considering I am using percentages, this wasn't useful.

**EDIT**

New issue implementing elfan's solution:

[Here is an event](https://www.facebook.com/events/544220282434185)  on fb where the image has offset_x in the actual fb page of -7px - but according the api, the offset_x = 50%

```
{
  "cover": {
    "offset_x": 50,
    "offset_y": 0,
    "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/s720x720/14681104_1307094859330152_7540791723420117074_o.jpg",
    "id": "1307094859330152"
  },
  "id": "544220282434185"
}
```

So, using the calculation `500px (width of my image) * offset_x % = 250px`

What am I doing wrong :-)

I have also noticed that there are some events which have crazy offsets, like 1800 for example. According to fb docs, it should be between 0-100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with the interpretation.

The value `50` from fb api apparently refers to the offset in percentage as when using it in `top`, which means percentage of the containing block's height ([spec here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top)). And that is different to when using it in `background-position` ([spec here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-position)). There is also [an article here](https://css-tricks.com/i-like-how-percentage-background-position-works/) that visually shows the difference.

If you want to use `background-position`, the solution is to use `px`.
Alternatively, you can use `top`, either as `%` or `px`.

I have made the following code to compare your code, fb code, and what the fix should be (for all alternatives):

```css
/* Your original code */
.event-image {
 width: 500px;
 height: 178px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url("https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-0/p600x600/14566476_1295215523823549_1334771895810946224_o.jpg");
 background-position: 0 50%;  /* "50" is from fb api, but not used correctly */
}

/* FB actual code */
.cover {
 width: 826px;
 height: 294px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.cover img {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: -147px;  /* 294px * 50% = 147px, this is the correct usage of "50" from fb api */
}

/* Your code if showing as big as FB image */
.bigger-image {
 width: 826px;
 height: 294px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url("https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-0/p600x600/14566476_1295215523823549_1334771895810946224_o.jpg");
 background-position: 0 50%; /* "50" is from fb api, but not used correctly */
}

/* The correct code using "background-position" */
.correct-image {
 width: 500px;
 height: 178px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url("https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-0/p600x600/14566476_1295215523823549_1334771895810946224_o.jpg");
 background-position: 0 -89px;   /* 178px * 50% = 89px, this is the correct usage of "50" from fb api */
}

/* The correct code using "top" in pct */
.correct-cover {
 width: 500px;
 height: 178px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.correct-cover img.pct {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: -50%;    /* the correct usage of "50" from fb api */
}

/* The correct code using "top" in px */
.correct-cover img.px {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0;
 top: -89px;  /* 178px * 50% = 89px, this is the correct usage of "50" from fb api */
}
```

```html
<h3>Your original code</h3>
<div class="event-image"></div>
<br />

<h3>FB actual code</h3>
<div class="cover">
 <img src="https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-0/p600x600/14566476_1295215523823549_1334771895810946224_o.jpg" />
</div>
<br />

<h3>Your code if showing as big as FB image</h3>
<div class="bigger-image"></div>
<br />

<h3>The correct code using "background-position"</h3>
<div class="correct-image"></div>
<br />

<h3>The correct code using "top" in pct</h3>
<div class="correct-cover">
 <img class="pct" src="https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-0/p600x600/14566476_1295215523823549_1334771895810946224_o.jpg" />
</div>
<br />

<h3>The correct code using "top" in px</h3>
<div class="correct-cover">
 <img class="px" src="https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-0/p600x600/14566476_1295215523823549_1334771895810946224_o.jpg" />
</div>
<br />
```

Additional explanation about why 46% looks correct in your original code:

`background-position: 0%` is the same as `top: 0px`

`background-position: 100%` is the same as `top: -197px`

`background-position: 50%` is the same as `top: -98.5px` (197 x 50%)

`background-position: 46%` is the same as `top: -90.62px` (197 x 46%), while the correct one is `top: -89px`, so that looks close enough.

Where does `197` come from?
The box size is 500 x 178px. The actual image size is 800 x 600px. The rendered/scaled image size due to `background-size: cover` is 500 x 375px.
The image height is 375-178 = 197px larger than the box height. Remember that when using `background-position: 100%`, the bottom edge of the image will meet the bottom edge of the box, which means `top: -197px`.

Comment: Thank you! That's definitely the correct answer :-) - I will let the bounty expire, then up it to 150 and award it to you asap.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty :) As a bonus, I have updated my answer with addtional explanation about the 46%.

Comment: I am running into some trouble implementing this solution, could you explain where I am going wrong - I will edit my question with the new issues.

Comment: A moment ago, I thought I already got the calculation which leads to 7px (for the second case), but somehow it doesn't work when I verified it again. And strangely, the image size from URL from FB api is 720x266px, while on the actual FB page is 800x296px. The actual fb event page also has a 7px gap on the right side of the image (see the white-to-gray gradient strip), because it is shifted by `left: -7px`. The 1800 of your third case is also strange, can you give me the json result of it? I will keep looking into this and will let you know again later.

Comment: Ye, it's confusing, and the confusion is coming from the fb docs vs actual api responses. Here's the 1800-json :-) `{
  "cover": {
    "offset_x": 1800,
    "offset_y": 0,
    "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/14925720_1675594702754596_8307502062667602009_n.png?oh=cceecb108e342889c4a1bc2a6df57469&oe=58CB1BB0",
    "id": "1675594702754596"
  },
  "id": "1124188834362717"
}`

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this method being used in regards to offsets from FB.

```
FB.api(artist, function (data) {
    $('.ed-cover img').attr('src', data.cover.source)
    .css("top", (-1 * data.cover.offset_y) + '%');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this answer was taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393742/how-to-compute-facebook-graph-api-cover-offset-y-to-pixel , and as I already stated, does not work for me.