# facebook graph api: offset_y offset_x

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hello I am trying to understand what offset_y means in facebooks graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/cover-photo/.

I have tried understanding this related post, but cannot. [how to compute Facebook graph api cover offset_y to pixel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393742/how-to-compute-facebook-graph-api-cover-offset-y-to-pixel)

For example, this event. https://www.facebook.com/events/1119146318216486/. produces an '"offset_y": 20' when calling the graph api

[image]

But, the actual offset is -4px: [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: That other question you are referring to is five years old. The documentation seems to be a little more explicit about what that value actually means now than it did back then; if anything, I'd use that as a starting point to try and make sense of it. (But from all SO questions if have come across so far on this, the whole thing does seem to be more or less of a mystery, and no one has had much luck making sense of it or actually applying it on a practical use case yet [what exactly is your's, btw.], so good luck ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values for `offset_x` and `offset_y` are percentages of the size of the original image, not pixel values.

The percentages will range from 0 to 100, and will be a percentage of the overflow offset value of the resized image for the space.

For example, I have an image that is 720x480 px. The cover photo space is 851x315 px, so when the photo is resized to fit that space, it is 851x567.33 px. If I drag that image halfway down when I am positioning it for my cover, the `offset_y` that is returned will be `50`. This translates to 50% of the "leftover" space that doesn't fit into the cover photo slot.

The "leftover" vertical (y) space will be 567.33 - 315 = 252.33 px. 50% of that space is 126.167. My `top` offset, in this case, will be -126.167 px.

So `offset_x` and `offset_y` are percentages of the pixel movement required to position the resized image into the photo space on Facebook.

```js
// These values retreived ahead of time (Graph API, etc.)
var offset_x = 0;
var offset_y = 50;
var fbCoverPhotoWidth = 851; // Known value, in pixels
var fbCoverPhotoHeight = 315; // Known value, in pixels

// Create an image from the cover photo URL returned by the Graph API
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-0/p480x480/your-photo-url-here.jpg";

// Calculate the scaling ratio
var ratio = Math.max(fbCoverPhotoWidth / img.width, fbCoverPhotoHeight / img.height);

// Convert the offset percentages to pixel values
var offset_x_pixels = Math.ceil(((img.width * ratio) - fbCoverPhotoWidth) * (offset_x / 100));
var offset_y_pixels = Math.ceil(((img.height * ratio) - fbCoverPhotoHeight) * (offset_y / 100));

console.log(offset_x_pixels);
console.log(offset_y_pixels);
```

Comment: Glad to help! Best of luck with this project.