# facebook graph api: understanding offset_y offset_x API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hello I am trying to understand what offset_y means in facebooks graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/cover-photo/.

> y_offset: When greater than 0% but less than 100%, the cover photo overflows
>   vertically. The value represents the vertical manual offset (the
>   amount the user dragged the photo vertically to show the part of
>   interest) as a percentage of the offset necessary to make the photo
>   fit the space.

I have tried using the solution in [facebook graph api: offset_y offset_x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238129/facebook-graph-api-offset-y-offset-x),
but it does work.

for example, this event https://www.facebook.com/events/164312630996898/. The event picture has a css top offset of -3px:

[image]

In order to calculate this, I will attempt to use the method in [facebook graph api: offset_y offset_x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238129/facebook-graph-api-offset-y-offset-x)

The image is 500x622px (when resized to fit), the event image space is 500x262px. 622px-262px = 360px. using the facebook graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=164312630996898%3Ffields%3Dcover&version=v2.12) gives an offset-y of 9:
[image]

so 9% of 360px is, 32.4px, but the actual answer should be 3px.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: could the solution be sitting in the code, because mathematically 3px (2.914px) is 9% of 32.4 which is 9% of 360 ... etc. ?

Comment: Honestly very weird numbers, I tried with 10 different images with somethings the offset varying from `-5, 0, 55,63,75, 169` and it still seems cryptic of a calculation to figure out how the calculate this figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have experimented with this a lot and I am 100% sure the `offset_x`, `offset_y` are not properly documented and may not be even sufficient in many cases to even depict the offset

In my case I used two images listed below and did some experiment with different drags

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

The event was created on

https://www.facebook.com/events/901430313369669/

[image: Event]

And data collected was below for the above 2 images

[image: Data collected]

For the 2nd image you can see that whether i kept the image left aligned, right aligned or center aligned the offset were always 0. But the `left` was still calculated. This means facebook is not share the offset information correctly. It is most probably a bug based on observation from second image.

Also weird thing is the `-77`, `177` entries from the first image

[image: Offset]

Comment: hey thanks for putting in all that effort :)
your conclusion is, is what I suspected. I have yet to find a solution to this problem.

I will  submit a bug to the facebook api team.

Comment: Any update on this?  Saw the facebook bug report was closed, but this is still clearly an issue